# Screen flickering on ultrawide monitor with AMD card

Tags: drivers, screen, flicker

I have installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu (KDE) on my desktop and I have screen flickering problem. This is 4th Linux I tried (deepin,Kali,elementary,Ubuntu-all have the same problem)
I am using ultrawide 2560x1080 screen and in native resolution screen flicker so much it is unusable.
Lowering resolution fix problem but makes everything ugly. To show you what is the problem I posted short video: https://youtu.be/9UdOxqmch1g
AMD drivers from website won't work, add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-driver won't work. Neither xrender or g2 or g3 fix the problem.

Hope someone can help me fix the problem.
Thank you

GPU: R9 270x Sapphire Dual-X
CPU: FX 6300
Monitor: LG 25UM57 P-25" 21:9 IPS LED

[Here is picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqGUS.png)

Comment: Please specify the exact GPU model and which driver you are using exactly, in your question.

Comment: I edited question with info

Comment: Can you run `lsmod | grep radeon` and `lsmod | grep amd` and include whichever one has output, in your question? You mentioned the GPU, CPU, and monitor, but not which graphics driver is actually being used.

Comment: I gave screenshoot of commands output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. New 4.12 kernel fixed problem  somehow.

Installed from here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.12-rc1/

1. download generic header+image for amd64
2. install with `sudo dpkg -i`
3. reboot
4. `uname -r` should show 4.12 if it worked.

Comment: I edited comment with a link.

Answer (score 0):

it happens to me wenever i have vga connected to laptop and both lvds and vga are lit, vga flickers; so i use xrandr to turn of lvds while working on vga

use `xrandr` to show you connected screens(names)
then use this to turn off 

`xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1280x1024 --rate 75
xrandr --output LVDS --off`

see your native resolution; care not to get yourself in the dark.. light up the target monitor before shuting the others off

`https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr`

the idea is that you might have multiple devices on.. so try specifically turning them off and keep only the display you use

edit: upon more reading you might use the `--rate xx` to change refresh rate or `cvt` program to generate new modes `https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8595940`

Comment: Did not help. Here is terminal output http://imgur.com/a/57HRh

Comment: Do you maybe have any other solution?

Comment: @stefan perovic upon more testing on my laptop-external screen setup i found out that in fact changing laptop screen brightness made flicker go away.. my conclusion is it has to do with parasitic noise from cc lamp driver. from more reading about ati `http://www.overclock.net/t/1037034/how-to-fix-dual-monitor-screen-flicker-ati-amd-guide` seems it has to do with memory speeds.. so again parasitic noise.. you could try testing the others video out connectors on card

Comment: @stefan perovic  from your posted video it seems you have signal dropout on hdmi.. can you connect to vga or dvi? or use a small hdmi cable.. like 1.5m

Comment: That link doesn't work,and I only use 1 monitor.
I cannot change input as my monitor only support HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

For my, the solution was to put GRUB in text mode. The problem was when the graphic card changed from the GRUB resolution to desktop resolution.